# Using list comprehension with iloc, isna(), sum() and if statement

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I'm wondering if there is a way to re-write the following code as a list comprehension. Also, I wonder if it's preferable over the loop in my case.

I have a pandas dataframe with the shape (5000, 92). The goal is to loop over each row, evaluate each column and count NaN values, then output True or False if the number of NaN's is greater than 88.
The working code is here:

```
nans =[]
for i in range(0,len(df)):
    if df.iloc[i,:].isna().sum() > 88:
        nans.append(False)
    else:
        nans.append(True)
```

I have tried the one below which isnt working:

```
[False for i in range(0,len(df)) if df.iloc[i,:].isna().sum() > 88 else True]
```

Any help/advice much appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you need invert boolena mask by `~` and count `sum` per rows:

```
nans = (~df.isna().sum(axis=1).gt(88)).tolist()
```

Your list comprehension working too, but is slowier if larger DataFrame:

```
nans = [not df.iloc[i,:].isna().sum() > 88 for i in range(0,len(df))]
```